# Trigger the right events for WebPage Input box to stop the value from resetting

Tags: html, vba

I am using VBA and trying to enter a value in an Input Box from a WebPage. After entering the value, when I press the submit button, the value resets. I tried several methods and functions like .focus, .change, or .keydown.

The line for the input box is the following:

```html
<"input ng-if=":: !uiInputNumberIncrementerCtrl.isTouchSupported" type="text" class="stepper-value ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty ng-valid-rate-validator ng-touched" ng-model="uiInputNumberIncrementerCtrl.inputValue" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur' }" data-input-box="" ng-focus="focus($event)" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" ng-change="blur($event)" ng-blur="defocus($event)" data-maxchars="12" data-number="" data-input-scrollto="" data-etoro-automation-id="input"">
```

```vb
Private Sub Watchlist_Information()
Dim IE As Object
Dim IE_Port As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim objSubCollection As Object
Dim buttonCollection As Object
Dim evt As Object
Dim valeur_heure As Object

Dim Wks As Workbook
Dim MBoard As Worksheet

Set Wks = ThisWorkbook
Set MBoard = Wks.Sheets("MBoard")

Dim i As Long
Dim RowRef As Long
Dim SelectedStock As Integer


RowRef = 11

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.navigate "https://www.etoro.com/watchlists"

' Wait while IE loading...
While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend

' Configuration for input boxes that require Keyboards inputs
Set evt = IE.document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
    evt.initEvent "change", True, False

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))
    'Find the slected stock based on ticker and issue a buy order
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ng-scope")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).childElementCount > 0 Then
        If objCollection(i).Children(0).childElementCount > 1 Then
            If objCollection(i).Children(0).Children(0).childElementCount > 0 Then
                If objCollection(i).Children(0).Children(1).Children(0).innerText = MBoard.Range("D3").Value Then
                objCollection(i).Children(1).Children(2).Children(1).Children(0).Click
                SelectedStock = i
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("box-tab-value ng-binding ng-scope")(1).Click

IE.document.getElementsByClassName("box-tab-value ng-binding ng-scope")(2).Click
Set evt = IE.document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
    evt.initEvent "change", False, True
    Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("stepper")
      objCollection(2).Children(1).Focus
      objCollection(2).Children(1).dispatchEvent evt
      objCollection(2).Children(1).Keydown
      objCollection(1).Children(1).Value = MBoard.Range("F17").Value
      objCollection(2).Children(1).Keydown
      objCollection(2).Children(1).Change
      objCollection(2).Children(1).Focus
      objCollection(2).Children(1).Blur
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ng-isolate-scope")(3).Click
```

I have no error messages. The value just resets when pressing the submit button.

Comment: what's the web-page url? And can we see a little more of the start of the code please.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the entire sequence

Comment: What’s an example value you want to enter?

Comment: An example of value is: 300. This is what in cell F17 resides.

Comment: Hummm.... I see a login screen. Am I supposed to enter fictitious details then press enter and hopefully getting invalid details entered message? Or: Looks like you actually need a login first then doing whatever it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I indeed need to login first (I do it manually when I first open the platform, then the login remains and I can use the macro without having to repeat it every time). If it helps, I can create a dummy account account to use.

Comment: if it replicates the problem sure.

Comment: Let me know if you set one up.